# How to keep a constant max on number of goroutines

Tags: go

```
for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
           go messenger(i)
           go messenger(i-1)
    }()
    wg.Done()
}
wg.Wait()
```

I am confused, wouldn't this for loop create 5 go-routines that are all synchronized? For some reason when I print out the `runtime.NumGoroutine()` it changes between 6 and 7, sometimes losing data as well.

Comment: `wg.Wait` will never actually block in this example since you call `wg.Done` in the same goroutine and loop iteration you call `wg.Add(1)`. By the time you get to `wg.Wait`, your code would have already called `Done` for each `Add`, so there will be nothing to wait on. Can you also post the definition of `messenger`?

Comment: runtime.NumGoroutine() reports **all** running goroutines, not just the once _you_ started deliberately.

Answer (score 0):

The `wg.Wait()` function should wait for all the running go routines but the after you start your anonymous go `func`,

```golang
go func() {
    go messenger(i)
    go messenger(i-1)
}()
```

, `wg.Done()` is executed as well and this decreases the Wait Group counter. This counter becomes `0` after the end of the loop and `wg.Done()` doesn't wait for anything.

So, if you want the wait group to wait on `wg.Wait()` for the completetion of the go routines then you should move `wg.Done()` inside the go `func`, like,

```golang
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    go messenger(i)
    go messenger(i-1)
}()
```

---

**One more point**: The `messenger` function is called as a go routine. This way the anonymous go function will not wait for them to complete as it will just create two go routines and exit. Is this the desired functionality? And, due to this `runtime.NumGoroutine()` is more than `5`.

Comment: Your proposed solution is vritually the same (as the OP's one): "So, if you want the wait group to wait on wg.Wait() for the completetion of the go routines" --- your code won't wait for the completion of goroutines.

Comment: Hi @zerkms, I had solved it in two parts, one was to add `wg.Done()` inside the anonymous function and the another was to not call the `messenger` function as go routine. I'm not sure which part I've missed. Can you please edit my answer?

Comment: Your only example is functionally identical to the problematic code.

Comment: I've asked the OP to add `wg.Done()` inside the anon func and not to call messenger func as go routine. How can I improve it?